# jQuery drag and drop DIV as well as adding a custom attribute to each toher

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I am really stuck on how to achieve this.

I am trying to create a user friendly drag and drop calculaor for some current ratings.

[image: Concept Layout]

I want to be able to drag DIV's from the column to the right (each DIV has a custom attribute call 'currentRating' I.E .  When I drag that div to one of the 4 boxes I want it to stay in that DIV and add the total of the box as well as the grand total.  I also want to be able to update the quantities per each div once it is in one of the 4 boxes.

Is this even achievable? I have got it working so I can drag and drop the DIV, but that is it.

This is what I have so far.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$(function() {
    $(".draggable").draggable();
    $(".item").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.append(ui.draggable);    

            var width = $this.width();
            var height = $this.height();
            var cntrLeft = (width / 2) - (ui.draggable.width() / 2);
            var cntrTop = (height / 10) - (ui.draggable.height() /10);

            ui.draggable.css ({
                left: cntrLeft + "px",
                top: cntrTop + "px"
            });

            count += $(".draggable").attr("rating");
            alert(count);
        }
    });
});

  $("#box_1").text(count);

});

</script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="item">
  <div class="draggable" rating="2">Text #1 <input style ="display: inline; width: 20px; float: right;" type="text" name="quantity" value="1" /></div>
  <div class="draggable" rating="1">Text #2 <input style ="display: inline; width: 20px; float: right;" type="text" name="quantity" value="1" /></div>
  <div class="draggable" rating="1">Text #3 <input style ="display: inline; width: 20px; float: right;" type="text" name="quantity" value="1" /></div>
  <div class="draggable" rating="1">Text #4 <input style ="display: inline; width: 20px; float: right;" type="text" name="quantity" value="1" /></div>
  <div class="draggable" rating="1">Text #5 <input style ="display: inline; width: 20px; float: right;" type="text" name="quantity" value="1" /></div>
</div>

    <div class="item">
    Total = <div id="box_1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>



</body>
```

Comment: Give us some code to work with. What's the code you've got to get it draggable/droppable

Comment: Updated with some code.

Comment: nearly there, just getting the finishing touches

Answer (score 0):

Got rid of positioning in JS as i didn't need it, you can add it in as needed per your site.

```js
$(function(){
var count=parseInt($("#box_1").text());
var quantity=parseInt($("#box_2").text());
var rating; 
var Inputvals;

$( ".draggable" ).draggable({revert:true});
  
    $(".item").droppable({ 
  
        drop: function(event, ui) {
   
           rating=parseInt(ui.draggable.attr('value'));
     Inputvals=parseInt(ui.draggable.children().val());
     
   alert(rating);
            $(this).append(ui.draggable);   

            count += rating;
             quantity+=Inputvals ;
    $("#box_1").html(count);
    $("#box_2").html(quantity);
        }
    });

 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item1">
  <div class="draggable" value="1">Text #1 <input  type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="Enter a Numeric Value" /></div>
  <div class="draggable" value="2">Text #2 <input  type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="Enter a Numeric Value" /></div>
  <div class="draggable" value="3">Text #3 <input  type="text" name="quantity"placeholder="Enter a  Numeric Value"  /></div>
  <div class="draggable" value="4">Text #4 <input  type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="Enter a  Numeric Value"/></div>
  <div class="draggable" value="5">Text #5 <input  type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="Enter a  Numeric Value" /></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item2">
    Draggable Values = <div id="box_1">0</div><br>Input values=<div id="box_2">0</div>
    </div>
```